# Rails and FactoryBot - unable to launch User model, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am trying to implement FactoryBot models into my Rspec tests. Those models look like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name { "MyString" }
    last_name { "MyString" }
    inbox 
    outbox 
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :outbox do
    user_id { 1 }
  end
  factory :inbox do
    user_id { 1 }
  end
end
```

And when I call "patient = create(:user)" in my Rspec test I get this error:

> ```
>  Failure/Error: patient = create(:user)     
>  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
>  Validation failed: User must exist
> ```

To provide a broader view, here are my models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :inbox
  has_one :outbox
  has_many :payments
  has_many :messages

end

class Inbox < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages

end

class Outbox < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages

end
```

and regarding part of schema.rb:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean  "is_patient", default: true
    t.boolean  "is_doctor",  default: false
    t.boolean  "is_admin",   default: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end

  create_table "outboxes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_outboxes_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "inboxes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_inboxes_on_user_id"
  end
```

What do I do wrong here that User in FactoryBot cannot pass a validation?

Comment: Is it possible your index on outbox and inbox requires a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `after(:build)`

```
factory :user do
  first_name { "MyString" }
  last_name { "MyString" }

  after(:build) do |user|
    user.inbox = create(:inbox, user: user)
    user.outbox = create(:outbox, user: user)
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!